# What to chose, html canvas of flash for web+android

Tags: flash, canvas

i have a coulple of ideas of games, which i want to develop for web (mb chrome, facebook) and lately build them for android/ios.

Should I choose flash of html canvas?

Comment: Any answer to this question is likely to be based on opinion alone, as you question is very broad and vague. Which programming languages are you familiar with? What have you tried already? What type of games would you like to develop?

Comment: Im familliar both with flash and javascript, canvas api. Games: arcade/puzzles. To say the truth other people' oppinions - is what i wanted to hear, thanks!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stackoverflow handles specific coding questions rather than general "what to choose" questions.

**You might ask your "what to choose" question on the Programmers site:**

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

My quick 2-cents:

Mobile is on the rise and Flash is dying on mobile.

So go with canvas for fast-paced games (like arcade games).

Go with SVG for slow paced games (like a puzzle).

If you have skills in Flash, there is a Flash-like canvas library called EaselJS you might check out:
 http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS